# Window sill on CMU is rotted, what is the best t way for me to replace this?

Tags: windows, exterior, sill, rot

The prior owner of my house renovated and installed new windows in the basement.

They, however, just left some wonky old wood behind as a sill and painted over it with some mortar and latex paint that quickly peeled away.

I'm trying to determine what the best way to remedy this is. Someone recommended that I remove the window, lay down a bed of mortar and install a new PVC sill and place the window back in. This sounds like an OK plan but I'm always open to ideas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the wood under the actual window rotting?